# How to list down how many user can access a file in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, acl

Like in windows we can right click and check the permissions for a particular file. This show us all the users and type of access they have for a file.

Do we have a similar command or process to list down a list of users who can access a specific file?

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 3):

The answer is:

```bash
getfacl <FILE_NAME>
```

Comment: This shows similar result as 'ls -lrt' (in a better fashion).

But, my requirement is little different. Let's say this is a path /dir1/file1

If user1 has access to dir1 and files inside it and user2 only have access to file1. Then if I check list of users who has access to file1, then it should show user1 and user2 as output.